# Using the Twilio API, Whatsapp approved Twilio number, pre-approved template, unable to receive whatsapp message

Tags: python, twilio, whatsapp

I have a Whatsapp enabled Twilio number, but I do not receive messages from it.

```
message = client.messages.create(
                              from_='whatsapp:+1910708xxxx',
                              body='This is your flight confirmation for '
                                   'IND-11 on 1/1/2022.',
                              to='whatsapp:+91xxxxxxxx'
```

However when I change the **from** number to the **Whatsapp sandbox number**, I do receive the message.

I did try to send a whatsapp message to my twilio number .. but I endup in my Messaging app inviting the number to use Whatsapp .. It is almost as if there are steps that needs to be done set Twilio number up for WA messaging ..

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your sandbox number because I found it in Twilio documentation:

> The Sandbox allows you to prototype with WhatsApp immediately using a shared phone number without waiting for your Twilio number to be approved by WhatsApp.

so it means if you're unable to send Whatsapp messages from your Twilio number then it's not approved by Whatsapp yet!

Comment: I don't have any issues with the sandbox number, it works as expected. I need to get it working with the number I want to use in production. the number has been approved by Whatsapp. Any other insights will be helpful.